# How to differentiate an integral with Leibniz Rule?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following integral expression:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\theta_p}\left(\theta_p-\theta\right) p(\theta \mid y) d \theta+\int_{\theta_p}^{\infty}\left(\theta-\theta_p\right) p(\theta \mid y) d \theta
$$
Taking the first-order derivative with respect to $\theta_p{ }$ provides
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\theta_p} p(\theta \mid y) d \theta-\int_{\theta_p}^{\infty} p(\theta \mid y) d \theta
$$

I need to apply the following rule:

$\frac{\partial \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x, y) d y}{\partial x}=f(x, b(x)) \frac{\partial b(x)}{\partial x}-f(x, a(x)) \frac{\partial a(x)}{\partial x}+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac{\partial f(x, y)}{\partial x} d y$

Unfortunately I do not see how this rule is applied. If someone could show me the intermediate steps, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a matter of matching the corresponding parts:

$$\begin{array}{rclclcl}
\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} \int_{\color{green}{a(x)}}^{\color{blue}{b(x)}} f(\color{red}x,\color{orange}t) \, d\color{orange}t & = & \displaystyle  f(x,\color{blue}{b(x)}) \frac{d\color{blue}b}{dx} & - &  \displaystyle  f(x,\color{green}{a(x)}) \frac{d\color{green}a}{dx} & + & \displaystyle \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \, dt \\[2ex]
\hline
\displaystyle \frac{d}{d\theta_p} \int_{\color{green}{-\infty}}^{\color{blue}{\theta_p}} \underbrace{(\color{red}{\theta_p}-\color{orange}\theta) p(\color{orange}\theta\mid y)}_{f(\color{red}{\theta_p},\color{orange}\theta)} \, d\color{orange}\theta & = & \displaystyle  f(\theta_p,\color{blue}{\theta_p}) \frac{d\color{blue}{\theta_p}}{d\theta_p} & - & \displaystyle  \lim_{\tau\to-\infty} f(\theta_p,\color{green}\tau) \frac{d\color{green}\tau}{d\theta_p} & + & \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\theta_p} \frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta_p} \, d\theta
\end{array}$$

The reduction to $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\theta_p} p(\theta\mid y)\,d\theta$ follows immediately; both $f(\theta_p,\theta_p)$ and $\dfrac{d\tau}{d\theta_p}$ vanish ($\tau$ is constant with respect to $\theta_p$), and differentiating $f$ is trivial.